# convert Linux grep command to windows

Tags: linux, grep, findstr

i would like to get help to convert this search string to windows command :

grep taapAccessTokenTrustedAudiences * | grep -v credentials | grep -v application-cloud.yml

Answer (score 1):

Hi 
 You should replace the `grep` with `findstr` and `-v` with `/V`

This command:

```
grep taapAccessTokenTrustedAudiences * | grep -v credentials | grep -v application-cloud.yml
```

Will be like that in windows:

```
findstr "taapAccessTokenTrustedAudiences" * | findstr /V "credentials" | findstr /V "application-cloud.yml"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Select-String:

```
Get-Content Application-Cloud.yml | Select-String ("taapAccessTokenTrustedAudiences *") | Select-String -NotMatch ("credentials")
```

Select-String on it's own will act as a normal grep and Select-String -NotMatch as grep -v